# Change user profile picture Javascript , PHP, HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a social network that gives the user the option to change their profile picture or keep it the same(default) . I asked a question about this and got an answer that helped me save the picture into my uploads folder but not how to change the user's profile photo .

The user will click the choose file button and then when the choose the file they will click the button that says change profile picture . When they do all of that I want the default picture to change to the picture that the user selected . Can someone  please help me ?

profile.php :

```
<form id="form2" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p id="p1">Change profile picture:</p> <br />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br />
<br><input id="sub1" type="submit" value="Change profile picture" name="submit"><br />
</form>

<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img id="myImg" src="default.png" width="200" height="150">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- The Close Button -->
<span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

<!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
<img class="modal-content" id="img01">

 <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
<div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

UPDATE !!

I've updated my code to save the image and then have it saved in the database but all this code is doing is saving it in my image folder and not saving it in my database . Please help me.

upload.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("connect.php"); 
include("auth_login.php"); 

$target_dir = "images/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

if(isset($_POST["change"])) {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

$q = mysqli_query ($conn, "UPDATE users SET userPic = '".$_FILES['fileToUpload']
['name']."' WHERE username = '" . $username . "'");

if($check !== false) {
echo "File saved - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
$uploadOk = 1;

} else {
echo "File is not an image.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to need a database, there, chief.

Comment: I have one with a users table . The table has id,username,pw and email . Should I use the same table or a different one ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I can answer your specific PHP question but it sounds like this is more of an architecture question you're posing as opposed to an actual question like why isn't this working.

I would suggest you have a auth table which keeps track of all of your users data such as username, email, profile_photo etc... Your profile_photo should be a string file path that points to the image that they are using.  By simply removing the old image and pointing to the new image you could solve this problem and you could keep your file system slim.   Another option is to give the ability for profile_photo to store multiple file path locations for each image they've uploaded.

Comment: I have one with a users table . The table has id,username,pw and email . Should I use the same table or a different one ?

Comment: It's really just personal preference, in Django I usually extend the profile table with a custom table for additional fields.   Sometimes it's messier to try to add a column to an existing table than to just create a new one.   The challenge with a new one is making sure a foreign key entry is added every time you add a new user to your existing user table.  In django I have a listener that says every time a new user is created, also create a new row for that user in the custom table.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to approach this is to hash the files and store the hash in a database, and then save the files with the hash as the name.

This way you can just create every user like

`insert into user (username, photo) values ('me', 'default_photo_hash')`

and then when the user updates his photo, you hash the new photo, save it, and

`update user (photo) values ('new_photo_hash') where username='me'`

Comment: How do I hash the files ?

Comment: Can I save the photo by itself instead of username and picture ?

Comment: For example, this is a bad idea, though, md5.  You probably want a more secure hash, though.  If you're not worried about security, though,( i.e. this seems to be a school project), then md5 is fine.

Comment: If you want a secure hash algo, use one of the secure ones, but make sure you base64 encode it and keep the file paths under 255 characters.

Comment: One big security measure that you can take is to never overwrite an existing image if the hash matches, but that still doesn't prevent someone from uploading, say, a pornographic image, and calculating a hash collision with a new picture of the president that no one has uploaded yet.

Comment: Hmm.  Forget all that.  Apparently sha1 will be good enough and is almost impossible to collide.  It also has filename friendly output and only 40 characters long.

Comment: `$hash = hash_file('sha1', $filepath).$originalFileExtension;`

Comment: I save password like this `                           $pw = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 14));   
` Can I save this like that but no passwords ?

Comment: First of all, stop passing in the extra options to password_hash.  Read the docs.  You shouldn't be doing that.  I still don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: `$hash = hash_file('sha1', $filepath).$originalFileExtension;` Now I'm confused on where to put it and what everything means

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
if($check !== false) {
 
 $userPic = hash_file('sha1', $filepath).$originalFileExtension;
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, fileToUpload) VALUES ('" . $username . "', '" . $userPic . "')";
 
    echo "File saved - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}`

Comment: And I'm getting one warning and five notices

Comment: I think you need more basic training, but you don't `insert into users` after you already have the user in the db.  you `update user ... where username = 'me'`

Comment: I have this `
 $userPic = hash_file('sha1', $target_file).$imageFileType;
 
 $sql = "UPDATE users WHERE(username = '" . $username . "' AND userPic = '" . $userPic . "')";` but nothing has changed

Comment: I'm still confused on how I save the picture to the database and then show it when the user changes the profile

Comment: NO.  `update user set userPic='a1be4337e9....' where username='me'` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: If you just tried `update user set userpic='blah'` you would be setting all the users pics to blah.  The where condition tells the statement which user object(s) you want to update.  In this case, username is unique, so only 0 or 1 rows can be updated.

Comment: This is SQL 101 and you really should be doing your own homework.

Answer (score 0):

I have smt like that on my own blog(it is php code! i have some problem with printing it on page):

```js
   if(isset($_FILES['profile']) === true){
 if(empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true){
 echo "<div class='img-file-error'>Please choose a file!</div>";
 }else{
 $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
 $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
 $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
 $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
 if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true){
 change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
header('Location: settings');
 exit();
 }else{
 echo "<div class='img-file-error'>Incorrect file type!<br>
 Allowed types: ";
 echo implode(', ',$allowed);
 echo ".</div>";
 }
 }
 }
 if(!empty($user_data['profile'])){
 echo '<img id="previewImg" class="img-settings" width="250px" src="', $user_data['profile'], '" alt="',$user_data['first_name'],'\'s profile image">';
 }
```

And js file:

```js
function onFileSelect(e){
  var f = e.target.files[0];
  if(f.type.match(/image.*/)){
   var reader = new FileReader;
   place = document.getElementById("previewImg");
   reader.readAsDataURL(f);
   reader.onload = function(e){ 
    place.src = e.target.result;
   }
  }
  else {
    alert('You can chose only pictures');
   };
 };
 if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob){
  document.querySelector("input[type=file]").addEventListener("change", onFileSelect, false);
 }else{
  console.warn( "Your browser does not support FileAPI");
 };
```